# Append a new array to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter Sessions to build a "Betslip".

I am adding the team name and odds to the bet slip and then plan to loop through each "bet" element to create a betslip.

The ideal array needs to look like :

```
 [betslip] => Array
        (
            [bet] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Rayo Vallecano
                    [odds] => 67/100
                )
            [bet] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Elche
                    [odds] => 1/100
                )
        )
```

However in my code, I just seem to be overwriting what is already there.

My current PHP code is as follows :

```
// Get Team Name
    $teamname = $this->uri->segment(3);

    // Get Odds
    $odds1 = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $odds2 = $this->uri->segment(5);

    $odds = $odds1;
    $odds .= "/";
    $odds .= $odds2;

    // Build An array titled Bet
    $bet = array(
        'bet' => array(
            'team'  =>  urldecode($teamname),
            'odds'  =>  $odds
        )
    );

    $betslip = $this->session->userdata('betslip');

    // Create The Betslip For The First Time...
    if(empty($betslip))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('betslip', $bet);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add To The Betslip Array...
        $betslip['bet'] = array(
            'team'  =>  urldecode($teamname),
            'odds'  =>  $odds
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('betslip', $betslip);
    }
```

How do I just append a bet to the existing bet slip array?

Is it possible to have multiple array keys with the same name too?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your ideal array cannot exist in php, since keys must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an **ideal array**

```
[betslip] => Array
        (
            [bet] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Rayo Vallecano
                    [odds] => 67/100
                )
            [bet] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Elche
                    [odds] => 1/100
                )
        )
```

it should be like

```
[betslip] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Rayo Vallecano
                    [odds] => 67/100
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [team] => Elche
                    [odds] => 1/100
                )
        )
```

---

```
<?php
$item = array();

$item2 = array(
    'team' => 1,
    'odds' => "1/100"
);



for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $item[] = $item2;
}

print_r($item);

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Murtaza I am more than happy to follow the ideal array. I can still loop through num elements when loading

Comment: hi, but your ideal array isn't possible.

Comment: a part from being "ideal" or not, the first array won't even work since equal keys will be overwritten

Comment: Sorry meant your suggested array, Makes sense to give it a unique ref in this case 0 and 1

Comment: @StuBlackett so you want to do it my way ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain that would be fine, Yeah.

Comment: @StuBlackett I have updated my answer, thats the way you do it.